# Installation of Rubycas-Server

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Can anyone help me for installing Rubycas-server.Please please,help me....

Comment: How could anybody help you if you didn't list any error?

Answer (score 0):

Heyyyy...
  I have successfully installed RubyCas-server..

https://github.com/rubycas/rubycas-server/wiki/Quick-Start